# how to get the file path from Python GUI and use file path in another python program

Tags: python, user-interface

This is my **main file**:

```
ExcelAppl = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    Workbook = ExcelAppl.Workbooks.Open('excel file path')
    Sheet = Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
```

This is the **Python GUI**:

```
root = Tk()
def callback():
    file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files","*.xls")])
    print "the file path  %s",file_path
    Text_button.insert(INSERT,file_path)
def execute():
    execfile("MainLibrary.py")
Browse_button = Button(text='Browse', command=callback).pack(side=LEFT, padx=10, pady=20, ipadx=20, ipady=10)
Execution_button = Button(text='Convert', command=execute).pack(side=BOTTOM, padx=10, pady=20, ipadx=20, ipady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

This is my query. I need to get the  `file_path` from the GUI and assign it to `Workbook = ExcelAppl.Workbooks.Open('excel file path')`. I need to get the path from the GUI and assign the path to my main code. Can anyone help?

Comment: Help with what, you didn't say what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `execfile()` here.

You could define a function in `main_library.py` instead:

```
import win32com.client

def do_something_with_excel_file(filename):
    app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(filename)
    worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
    # use `worksheet` ...

if __name__=="__main__":
   import sys
   # get filename from command-line if called as a script
   do_something_with_excel_file(sys.argv[1])
```

Then you could import it in your GUI code:

```
import tkFileDialog
from Tkinter import as tk

import main_library

def browse():
    path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Excel files","*.xls")])
    file_path.set(path)
    print "the file path  %s", path

def convert():
    root.destroy() # quit gui
    main_library.do_something_with_excel_file(file_path.get())

root = tk.Tk()
file_path = tk.StringVar()
tk.Label(root, textvariable=file_path).pack()
tk.Button(text='Browse', command=browse).pack()
tk.Button(text='Convert', command=convert).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: iam getting this error."AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client'", whether iam missing some thing

Comment: @user3127942: `win32com.client` might be a submodule that should be explicitly imported. I've updated the answer